# Compiling on Android device by Wireless network

Tags: android

Is it possible to run an Android app from my IDE on a real device that is only connected with WiFi to the PC ? using IP address ? 
(not plugged-in with a cable as it is usually)
if so tell how to .

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can using **ADB via network**

Comment: Thank  you @Aadi. please can you give example ?

Comment: Search the net.. If you have a custom ROM it will be in the developer options

Comment: Some custom Roms have the option already under settings>developer options. Others you'll have to use an app from play store, or other means. You'll most definitely need a rooted device though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)